# Python deepcopy of a list with duplicated elements

Tags: python

I know copy and deepcopy of a list.However, this question is a bit different, because my original list is generated by multiplying element.

First I generate original list by `list_ori = [[0]*3]*3`.
What I want is revising `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]` and then get `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`

I tried with following code.

```
import copy
list_ori = [[0]*3]*3
list_copy = copy.deepcopy(list_ori)
list_copy[0][0] =1 
print(list_copy)
```

Thus,I got `[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]`.
But actually,I want to get `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`

I have 2 naive solutions, but I was wondering is there a more clear way to deal with `list_ori = [[0]*3]*3` by deepcopying and then revising it?

Two naive solutions:

1

```
list_ori = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
list_copy = copy.deepcopy(list_ori)
list_copy[0][0] =1 
print(list_copy)
```

I change the generating method of list.The list_ori is not with duplicated elements in a list.

2

```
m = n = 3
test = [[0] * m] * n
print(test)
test_copy =  [copy.copy(element) for element in test]
test_copy[0][0] = 1
print(test_copy)
```

This method  iterates elements of a list. Will this method destroy the structure of list?

Comment: Don't *write* `[[0] * m] * n` if you don't want the behavior it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all with `list_ori = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]`, there is no need to deepcopy, just do:

```
list_ori = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
list_copy[0][0] = 1 
print(list_copy)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you! It is the same with my solution 1. But I wanna know why `copy.deepcopy` failed in my example code

Comment: @Travis Happy to help, regarding `deepcopy`, it fails because you're copying the based list, not copying directly to the sublists too.

Comment: @Travis see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: I don't think this answer answers the question even a little. OP is asking why `deepcopy` doesn't give him three different objects of `[0]*3`. According to the source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/16323cb2c3d315e02637cebebdc5ff46be32ecdf/Lib/copy.py#L138 . It seems `deepcopy` caches the same instances(have the same `id`).